# How to display text being held in a int variable?

Tags: c#

My variable holds some text but is currently being stored as an int (the class used reads the bytes at a memory address and converts to int.  Variable.ToString just displays the decimal representation, but doesn't encode it to readable text, or in other words, I would now like to convert the data from int to string with ascii encoding or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable text"?

Comment: If it's an `int` variable then it's not holding text - it's just holding a number. How did you get from the original text to the number in the first place?

Comment: `int` doesn't store text. You might be confused. Debug it properly, you might see whats going wrong on the code.

Comment: A number usually is well understood when displayed as digits. Which format  do you think is more 'readable'

Comment: @ Tim: It is a pointer to an address holding text, but the class I used to read the pointer stores it as an int. I know its text because I used a debugger.
@ Jon: Specifically with a call to a readprocessmemory class using: int Readpointer = Trainer.ReadPointerInteger("myprocess", Base, new int[1] { 0x13D8 }); // base is the base address of the process, the int array is the hex offset to the pointer holding the text. 
@Siva, I may need to find another class which stores it as a byte[] actually, but still will be left with the problem of encoding it.

Comment: @user1166981: A pointer to an address holding text is *not* a variable holding some text. They're fundamentally different, and I don't see how you could possibly have expected anyone reading the question to have guessed what you meant without referring to your previous questions (which you didn't mention). Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Additionally, using an `int` for a pointer is a really bad idea - what if it's a 64-bit process? This is what `IntPtr` is for.

Comment: @ Jon, I didn't want to confuse anyone with issues relating to this problem which has been left unanswered in another question, rather ask specific questions to piece it together eventually myself. I know they are different, didn't mean to say a pointer was a variable if I have somewhere.  But coming back to the problem at hand since you have read my other quetion, why is this so difficult? I posted in the earlier question the class I am using, I just want to change the format to ascii!!! grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo (based on our Q+A above).

Note: Settings a string with the null terminator as a test, then encoding it into ASCII bytes, then using unsafe (you will need to allow that in Build Option in project properties), itearte through each byte and convert it until 0x0 is reached.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ok = "OK" + (char)0;
            var ascii = Encoding.ASCII;

            var bin = ascii.GetBytes( ok );

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            unsafe
            {

                fixed (byte* p = bin)
                {
                    byte b = 1;
                    var i = 0;
                    while (b != 0)
                    {
                        b = p[i];

                        if (b != 0) sb.Append( ascii.GetString( new[] {b} ) );
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
        }
```

Note the FIXED statement, this is required managed strings/arrayts etc are not guaranteed to be statically placed in memory - this ensures it during that section.

Comment: Hi Wolf, thanks for getting me on the right path, I managed to do it using something like this:   while (Readpointer != 0) get byte from address, if (Readpointer != 0)  myStrings.Add(Readpointer);   textoffset6++; byte[] myStringsArray = myStrings.ToArray();    textBox119.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myStringsArray);

Answer (score 1):

assuming an int variable

```
    int x=10;
```

you can convert this into string as

```
    string strX = x.ToString();
```

Try this

```
    string s = "9quali52ty3";
    byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    foreach(byte b in ASCIIValues) {
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
```

Comment: The result of that is still 10 and not the ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me.  The address I am reading holds 1 byte: '6F', and the address next to it (address+1 offset) is 6B, this spells "ok" which is the text I want to display.  The text is terminated with the final address offset being a 0 byte.  The function I am now using gives me a byte variable, and if I do textbox1.text = variable;, it shows "111", the decimal representation of "o", or the first letter of the text I want.  I think what you have written 'almost' allows me to do what I want, but how would you modify it to bring the bytes into the array from offsets up to the 0?

Answer (score 0):

[Int32.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx) has an overload that takes a format string.  Take a look at the available format strings and use one of those.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: For example you can call `i.ToString("c")` to have it print the string out as currency.  All the options are listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx, but reading the comments in your question this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: They seem to have all representations other than ASCI, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your previous question, the int you have is (probably) a pointer to the string.  Depending on whether the data at the pointer is chars or bytes, do one of these to get your string:

```
var s = new string((char*)myInt);
var s = new string((sbyte*)myInt);
```

Comment: Do you mean that the int is the decimal of the hex eddress? If I use the same function to read another pointer which points to an address holding a number, it displays as a number and not an address.

Answer (score 0):

OK. If you variable is a pointer, then Tim is pointing you in the right direction (assuming it is an address and not an offset from an address - in which case you will need the start address to offset from).

If, on the other hand, your variable contains four encoded ascii characters (of a byte each), then you need to split to bytes and convert each byte to a character. Something like this `Console.WriteLine(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(myUint).ConvertTo(myUint, typeof(string)));` from [Here - MSDN ByteConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.byteconverter.aspx)

Comment: hello! I do believe this may be what I am looking for, so I will work on it this evening and report back!

Comment: I did some more digging and can confirm that the function returns the contents of the address, not a pointer address.  The text I want to capture is "ok", and in the address is the byte: 6F (which is the letter 'o' in ASCII), and at the address + offset of 1 is the hex 6B ('k' in ASCII), the address 1 more offset further is a 0, which terminates the string for my purposes.  I found this out by modifying the class to return the bytes found at the address pointed to, so it seems I may need to write some kind of iterative function to store the bytes at each offset until 0 is found in an array.

Comment: As you already have the bytes, simply loop through and convert them and stop at the null. var ascii = Encoding.ASCII;var str = ascii.GetString(bytes);

Comment: I only have the first byte, the function just returns the value from one address which if I do textbox1.text = variable;, it shows '111' the decimal of 6F, or "o" if you lookup the ASCII tables, the first letter of the text I want.

Comment: With your code I now have the letter "o" displayed!!!, now the next problem of itertating through the address offsets until the 0 byte!

Comment: You can pass the whole array of bytes in rather than just the first one. You will need to create an array and add each byte until you get the zero (don't add that as it will possibly cause the ASCII encoder to do funny things). You can simply get the bytes from subsequant addresses until null (0x00) is hit in the same loop that builds tha array - then pass the lot though GetString

Comment: Added another answer with a quick test which works - you would have to substitute your address etc.